# How to generate the actual results of an IRF() function within the vars package?

Tags: r, regression, var, autoregressive-models

Somehow, I am unable to generate the actual underlying values of the IRFs.  See code of a simple VAR model.

`irf5<-irf(var2, impulse = "libor", response = "y", n.ahead = 10, ortho = TRUE, boot = TRUE, CI = 0.95, runs = 100)`

I can generate the resulting IRF plots just fine with this code:

```
plot(irf5)
```

But, I can't generate the underlying values.  I'd like to do so to have precise figures.  Visually interpreting IRFs is not that accurate.  Using the summary() did not provide me this information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need just to write irf5 in command line and push ctrl+enter. If you can plot irf, so there are no errors, you can easily get IRF's values. In other words, in`irf5<-irf(var2,....)` you just generate and save new variable, but not call to it

Comment: dr.dre, thanks for the suggestion.  4 months later, I am now busy working on different types of project.  But, I will gladly revisit this issue and try what you just suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the values by using irf5$irf